# А разговор — это же практически, то есть(,) например(,) это латинского не касается, самая главная часть языка

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые?

> А разговор — это же практически, то есть(,) например(,) это латинского не касается, самая главная часть языка.

Comment: Обе запяьые нужны. Вводное слово не связано грамматически ни со следующей частью, ни с союзом _то есть_. Обособление по обычным правилам.